# Monobjc MSBuild tasks not working (additional libraries/excluded assemblies/additional assemblies)

Tags: macos, mono, xamarin, xbuild, monobjc

I'm trying to export/compile my monobjc Cocoa Application as a Native Application.  I made the project in Xamarin and have confirmed all the properties are correct, and I do get a successful build.  However, I'm trying to specify a few assemblies to exclude for licensing purposes and include additional libraries.  I saw that there is the option to specify additional libraries/assemblies to include/exclude either by adding them to the `<AddtionalLibraries>` tag in the csproj or through Xamarin.  However, specifying the libraries seems to do nothing in terms `BundleNative` target.  I've tried specifying absolute paths, and relative paths to the output directory.  I'm specifying Additional libraries in the form of:
`libtest_library.dylib`, and excluded assemblies like `Monobjc.dll`. Is there something wrong with the options to add/exclude assemblies (thus I need to file a bug) or am I missing something ?

(in the csproj file, it looks like `<ExcludedAssemblies>Monobjc.dll</ExcludedAssemblies>` under the appropriate Project->PropertyGroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExcludedAssemblies` tag should work. Its goal is to exclude some assemblies from being embedded in the generated binary. That also means that these assemblies should be accessible elsewhere (i.e. the `Resources` folder).

For the `AddtionalLibraries`, this is clearly a bug. Can you file one ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, will file a bug for the Additional Libraries.